# Create and access DOM element in javascript (Dojo)

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

My javascript creates the HTML statically (Bad practice, I know! But legacy code, can't help it). I need to create a div and access it somehow to append something to it in dojo (JavaScript Library). How do I do that?

```
if (someCondition) {
      html += "<span style=" " class='someClassName'></span>"
}
else {
      html += "<div id='"+id"+-sample-id class='divClass'>" +
              "    <div class ='column col-md-8' dojoattachpoint='_sampleDojoAttachPoint'>" +
"</div>" +
"</div>" ;
}
```

Now, I need to access this attachpoint to append child node to it in some other function.

Comment: check the dojo [tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dom_functions/index.html) for dom manipulation.

Comment: We'll probably need more than that. Is this inside a widget? What happens to the variable `html`? If we don't know how this piece of HTML actually ends up being attached to the DOM, then we can't help you with adding more things to it I'm afraid. Try to give a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use

```
dom.byId("yourIdHere")
```

to acess the node. Make sure you do this, when the Node is fully loaded and accessible.

See Reference here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom.html#dojo-dom

Also you can do it by using dojos query like

```
 require(["dojo/query"],function(query){
     var nl = query(".divClass");
 });
```

See Reference here : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html#dojo-query

Like mentioned above from frank, i would read the dom-tutorial.

Regards

Comment: Going through tutorials helped. Thanks everyone!